# Flow type distinguish between subtype union

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have this union of extended subtypes example:

```
type TypeA = {|
    type: "a",
    value: number,
|};

type TypeB = {|
    type: "b",
    value: Array<number>,
|};

type SuperType =
    | TypeA & {|
        color: string,
    |}
    | TypeB;

function test(val: SuperType): void {
    if (val.type === "b") {
        // Flow should probably know that val.value is an array here
        console.log(val.value.length);
    }
}
```

([live flow.org/try link here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8A+AoAkKSAXFAEQCGxANFlDVAG6kA2ArhEQHbMC2ARhAE5UMAXwDcWLPmhxIAIRTpseeEWI9K1WgxZsoCfv1IgAPJ14CAfELESpUAMrNI-GdGSacGWPCQAyRZo0OADGAPaMofxEAM7A-ACW7ADmVLRQIrherrLiWABmzOzBwPGh7FDAELEAFNpEjs6uAJREdKHxACboHvF5ULVMAHR2yKMk6k3daUEA9DNQAGIRAO5Q0QAWocyMXWD8oTykPIwgUADW7KGrwOukwPRD2qxQ8dFQpOWkBkZQ6wIQgVoITK0XCEEGESSA0Ygye4MYEGSNya4jSwiwwiAA))

However, at the end, when I attempt to take advantage of [Disjoint Unions with exact types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types), it fails:

```
20:         console.log(val.value.length);
                                 ^ Cannot get `val.value.length` because property `length` is missing in `Number` [1].
References:
3:     value: number,
              ^ [1]
```

I can't figure out if Flowtype doesn't support this or if I am doing something wrong. This is happening on Flow 0.66. Note that this works if I remove the `{| color: string |}` bit.

Comment: Can't you put `color: string,` inside `TypeA`?

Comment: I can't (this is a minimal example of a more complex type where I really can't), but in the meantime I managed to make this work using the `...` (spread operator) instead of `&` (intersection). Not sure why it works with spread, I thought the two operators were equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SuperType`, use the spread operator `...` instead of the intersection operator `&`:

```
type TypeA = {|
    type: "a",
    value: number,
|};

type TypeB = {|
    type: "b",
    value: Array<number>,
|};

type SuperType =
    | {|
        ...TypeA,
        color: string,
    |}
    | TypeB;

function test(val: SuperType): void {
    if (val.type === "b") {
        // Flow should probably know that val.value is an array here
        console.log(val.value.length);
    }
}
```

[Live demo on Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8A+AoAkKSAXFAEQCGxANFlDVAG6kA2ArhEQHbMC2ARhAE5UMAXwDcWLPmhxIAIRTpseeEWI9K1WgxZsoCfv1IgAPJ14CAfELESpUAMrNI-GdGSacGRZtq0AdAGuCFS+OADGAPaMEfxEAM7A-ACW7ADmIbQiuF6usuJYAGbM7GHASRHsUMAQCQAU2kSOzq4AlER0EUkAJugeSQVQ9Ux+dshjJOotvb40OAD0c1AAYtEA7lBxABYRzIw9YPwRPKQ8jCBQANbsEevAm6TA9MParFBJcVCklaQGRlCbAggPlo4QqcSiED80VSQ0YfhekMYEDSdxa4l8wiwwiAA)

Comment: The reason [`&` intersection](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/) doesn't work is that the `&` in `TypeA & {| color: string |}` doesn't modify `TypeA`, but merely adds an extra constraint: the value must be `TypeA` and `{| color: string |}` at the same time. This is of course impossible: the object can't contain only `color` while also only containing `type` and `value`. `...` spread inside an object type, on the other hand, creates a single new merged type, as you wanted.